# preg_replace HOW TO: remove from $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] everything .. but FILE name

Tags: php, preg-replace

For example this is $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] output:

> /foldername/index.php

I want to end up with index.php

MANY THANKS ! 
(ps. and I don't need to get index.php name in any other way for exampel: using  basename(**_*FILE*_**) which works great but not if placed in include file. If then we try to get the filename of the file it will tell me the include filename not the one included in.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regex required. Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
echo basename($_SEVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

`basename()` will return the filename from a given path. Output:

```
index.php
```

Comment: will base name not be executed inside the include file like basename(_FILE_) does???

Comment: You might also want to know that there is the opposite version: `dirname()`. It will return the path without the file name.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** hek2mgl has a much better answer.

One way to do it:

```
$parts = explode( '/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
$file_name = end( $parts );
```